# Handlebars - passing an value dynamically to an if condition

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am building a website using Ember. In my website, I have to load page content dynamically based on the following json (which is received from an API):

myData: [

{id: "1",**type: "A"**, **text: "Header1"**}, {id: "2", **type: "B"**, **text: "1"**}, {id: "3", **type: "B"**, text: "2"},

{id: "4", **type: "A"**, text: "Header2"}, {id: "5", **type: "B"**, text: "3"},

{id: "6", **type: "A"**, text: "Header3"},{id: "7", **type: "B"**, text: "4"}, {id: "8", **type: "B"**, text: "5" }

]

Based on the above json values, my page must look in the following design:

```
Header1
1
2

Header2
3

Header3
4
5
```

That is:

- First, I need to iterate 'myData' array and check the value of ***type*** key.
- If the value of *type* is *A* -> Need to display the value of its corresponding *'text' key* in header
- If the value of *type* is *B* -> Need to display the value of its corresponding *'text' key* below header

My JsBin code is given at: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ujUfuru/1/edit

I have iterated and retrieved the values of *text* successfully as follows:

```
{{#each myData}}
    <li>
        {{text}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Now, I need to **check the value of type** in array.

- If the type's value is A, need to display the value of its corresponding ***'text' key*** in header and
- if the type's value is B, need to display the value of its corresponding ***'text' key*** below header.

tried with the following code:

```
{{#each myData}}
   {{#isHeader type myData.type}}
       {{myData.text}}   //Header content - type A values
   {{else}}
       {{myData.text}}   //type B values
   {{/ifCond}}
{{/each}}

Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('isHeader', function(key, value, options){
    if(value == 'A'){
        console.log("header");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("below header");
        return false;
    }
});
```

However, the type condition check is not working. Can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong?

```
{{#isHeader type myData.type}}
```

How can I pass the type's value dynamically to handlebars? *myData.type* seems to be wrong.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try this implementation:

Template:

```
<script id="test-template" type="text/x-handlebars-tempalte">
    {{#each myData}}
        {{{textProcessor this}}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

JS

```
var data = {myData : [{id:1,type:'A',text:"Header 1"},{id:2,type:'B',text:"1"},{id:3,type:'B',text:"2"},{id:4,type:'A',text:"Header 2"},{id:5,type:'B',text:"3"},{id:6,type:'A',text:"Header 3"},{id:7,type:'B',text:"4"},{id:8,type:'B',text:"5"}]};

Handlebars.registerHelper('textProcessor',function(obj){
  var isHeader = obj.type==="A"?true:false;
  if(isHeader){
    return "<h1>"+obj.text+"</h1>";
  }else{
    return "<span>"+obj.text+"</span>"
  }
});

var source= $("#test-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var html = template(data);
$("#container").append(html);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I think you just want to display the object's text value in different DOM element.

So textProcessor helper will check its type and return the text with right element.

My example is in a pure js environment. Ember.js uses standard handlebars lib and this could be applied to your project too.

Hope this is helpful for you.

> **EDIT: If you want to achieve this in your way.**

Template

```
{{#each myData}}
  {{#isHeader type myData.type}}
    {{myData.text}}   //Header content - type A values
  {{else}}
    {{myData.text}}   //type B values
  {{/isHeader}}
{{/each}}
```

JS

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isHeader',function(key,value,opt){
  if(value==="A"){
    console.log("header");
    return opt.fn(this);
  }
  console.log("below header");
  return opt.inverse(this);
});
```